# How to select child element after 3rd or element after any position only

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to select child element after some position?
For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
  <li>seventh</li>
</ul>
```

I want to select all `li` item escaping first, second and third.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `nth-child` selector with the appropriate offset.

`n` takes on values starting with 0, 1, 2... so this will select the 4th, 5th, 6th ... child elements of the `ul`.

```css
li:nth-child(n+4) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>fourth</li>
  <li>fifth</li>
  <li>sixth</li>
  <li>seventh</li>
</ul>
```